# Scrapy problems with multiple urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping data from multiple urls, this way:

```
import scrapy

from pogba.items import PogbaItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pogba"
    allowed_domains = ["fourfourtwo.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459525/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459571/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459585/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459614/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459635/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459644/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459662/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459674/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459686/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459694/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459705/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459710/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459737/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459744/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02",
        "http://www.fourfourtwo.com/statszone/21-2012/matches/459765/player-stats/74208/OVERALL_02"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        Coords = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="pitch"]/*[contains(@class,"success")]'):
            item = PogbaItem()
            item['x'] = sel.xpath('(@x|@x1)').extract() 
            item['y'] = sel.xpath('(@y|@y1)').extract() 
            Coords.append(item)
        return Coords
```

Tha problem is that with this situation i have a csv with about 200 lines, while for each url i have about 50 line. Scraping one url at time works fine, but why i have different results if i set multiple urls?

Comment: For all of the links, getting 330 rows, for the last one 58 - are you sure there is a problem?

Comment: Scraping the urls one by one i get a total of 700 rows, scraping them all together gives me a 170 rows csv. Why?!

Comment: Hm, just a quick check. What if you would slow down the crawling by tweaking the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`? Does it make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Through the scrapy project settings: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY.

Comment: Now it's fine! I've set `DOWNLOAD_DELAY`=1 and `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS `=4. You can post these settings so i can accept your answer. Thank you, one more time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adjusting the crawling speed and slow down a little bit by increasing the delay between the requests ([`DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY)) and decreasing the amount of concurrent requests ([`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-CONCURRENT_REQUESTS)), e.g.:

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 4
```